# How to get Business Entity Attributes in Oracle EBS through PL/SQL API

Tags: plsql, oracle-ebs

I need to get all attribute for Business Entity like Item, BOM, PO or SO  through PL/SQL.
Is there any API for getting attribute for each Business Entity ?

Comment: Not enough information in your question, what attributes do you need data for ?

Comment: @Sudipta All attribute which are come at UI

Comment: There are two options, 1. Check `Record History` from help menu, this will give you a standard oracle view, which can be used to fetching the details. 2. Check the form code. Forms are available in `AU` Top

Comment: Thanks for comment Sudipta, 2nd Option is not clear to me, can you please explain it in detail ?

Comment: you can find the form name via `Help -> About -> Form Name`. The form code, `*.fmb` will be available in `AU_TOP-> forms -> US -> *.fmb`. you can download the `fmb` file to check how and what all data is being populated in the form

Comment: .fmb file is encrypted and, I think fields in form were statically defined. I need those attribute detail at run time. For Example, if  I make Item as Object and want to fetch all attribute(name) for  Item at run, how it is possible, Is there any dictionary table/view where all object and there attribute are define or is there any API which will give all attribute for any object